# how to divide an image to blocks and take dct of those

Tags: matlab, block, dct

I want to divide an image to k*k blocks then take `dct` of each block.I add zero padding to image so size of image is integer factor of block's size. I write this code, but i don't know how to take `dct` of blocks and put result in a matrix with same size of image.

```
[m,n]=size(I);
m1=floor(m/K);
n2=floor(n/K);
if(m1~=m/K)
  row=m1*K+K;
else
  row=m;
end
if(n2~=n/K)
  col=n2*K+K;
else
    col=n;
end
I_pad=zeros(row,col);
% copy image I to I_pad
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        I_pad(i,j)=I(i,j);
    end
end
% this loop move on blocks of image
for i=1:K:row
    for j=1:K:col
        for i2=i:i+K-1
            for j2=j:j+K-1
               % this for move of one block
            end
        end
   end
end
```

Comment: You can try using _blockproc_ instead of heavy loops...

Comment: I can't use `blockproc`. My Professor don't let me(:

Answer (score 0):

You can see the below code on how to divide the given image/matrix into required number of blocks. Use mat2cell to achieve the task. Before to mat2cell, I have padded zeros along rows and columns so that the given matrix gets exactly divided into equal blocks.

```
I = imread('peppers.png') ;
I = rgb2gray(I) ;
[nx,ny] = size(I) ;
%% to split into kx*ky blocks 
kx = 5 ; ky = 5 ;
%% Chnage dimensions of image so that exactly divisible 
nx0 = nx+(kx-mod(nx,kx)) ;
ny0 = ny+(ky-mod(ny,ky)) ;
%%
I1 = uint8(zeros(nx0,ny0)) ;
I1(1:nx,1:ny) = I ;
%% Divide into blocks 
kx0 = nx0/kx ; % rows in block
ky0 = ny0/ky ; % columns in block 
Y = mat2cell(I1, repmat(kx0,[1 size(I1,1)/kx0]), repmat(ky0,[1 size(I1,2)/ky0]));
```

YOu can access a block using Y{i,j}. I think you know what to do next.